# csrf token value missing after form post

Tags: django

I have a form posting to self.
The form post works perfectly the first time. But the form loads after form post, the csrf value is missing when the form loads.

Here's the code

```
def index(request):
    errormessage = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            test_model = form.save(commit= False)
            #add some fields
            test_model.save()
            #some processing
        else:
            errormessage = "Please fix the errors and try again."
    else:
        form = TestModelForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'errors': errormessage, 'form' : form})
```

CSRF token is inserted with following syntax

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

This is HTML during first page load

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="mjezd6QwxpznO1WMDavAMRDA3e2pIhu7">
```

This is the HTML of page load after posting

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="">
```

Can anyone tell what may be the issue?

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: some code please. Im guessing you need to return the form in the post response. But I cant be sure without seeing your view and template code, sorry

Comment: I'm adding some more field other than post data to model

Answer (score 0):

try changing `return render(request, 'index.html', {'errors': errormessage})` to `return render(request, 'index.html', {'errors': errormessage, 'form': form})` and adding `{% csrf_token %}` to your template file. This should solve the issue. For more information please see [the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#the-view)

Comment: form is already being passed to the template. sorry had removed it while posting code here.

Comment: Does your form look like this?

`<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>`

Comment: For csrf, it's same and we have manually coded html for form fields

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
if form.is_valid():
    test_model = form.save(commit= False)
    #add some fields
    test_model.save()
    #some processing
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'errors': errormessage, 'form' : form})
else:
    errormessage = "Please fix the errors and try again."
```